# Disable edits to a file

Tags: c#, windows, file, text-editor

I created a program in C# which read some lines in a database and store them in a RTF file, after that the file is converted to a another extension of file to be opened by a program. those files are some bills and what i want to do is prevent edits to those bills avoiding problems with clients if ever user make some mistakes.

I tried to go to those file properties and set them as read only but when opened by that ERP, they can still be edited.

Is there a way to prevent other programs/user from editing files?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the user rigths for the file, so that no one besides you can edit the file (admin access or what ever).
2. Keep the file open in your application, so that now one besides you can write to the file. (Open as FileStream or something else).